# R expanding out a data.table

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I've the following situation. A data.table that looks as follows

```
x = data.table(
 id1 = c('a','b','c'),
 id2 = c('x','y','x'),
 val = c(0.2,0.3,0.5))
```

I have two other data tables that give a mapping between the values in `id1` and `id2` which look like the following

```
id1.dt = data.table(
 id1 = c('a','a','a','b','b','c'),
 fid = c('1232','3224','3434','234','231','332')
)
```

and

```
id2.dt = data.table(
 id2 = c('x','x','y','y'),
 fid = c('334','443','344','24')
)
```

What I would like to be able to do is to expand out the above data.table `x` by preserving the `values` column such that I get a full cross join but by using the `fid` column. So the expected final table is

```
id1 id2 val
1232 334 0.2
1232 443 0.2
3224 334 0.2
3224 443 0.2
3434 334 0.2
3434 443 0.2
...
```

Basically, for each row in `x` I want to take all fid values of `id1` and `id2` from the other two tables and preserve the `val` value. I've tried using `CJ` but didn't get far with it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit awkward but this should do it:

```
setkey(x, id1)
(setkey(x[id1.dt], id2))[
  id2.dt, allow.cartesian=T][
  order(val), -(1:2)
]
```

Produces:

```
    val  fid fid.1
 1: 0.2 1232   334
 2: 0.2 3224   334
 3: 0.2 3434   334
 4: 0.2 1232   443
 5: 0.2 3224   443
 6: 0.2 3434   443
 7: 0.3  234   344
 8: 0.3  231   344
 9: 0.3  234    24
10: 0.3  231    24
11: 0.5  332   334
12: 0.5  332   443
```

You can also try `merge.data.table` to achieve a similar result in a somewhat more intuitively graspable form:

```
merge(
  merge(x, id1.dt, by="id1"), 
  id2.dt, by="id2", allow.cartesian=T
)[, -(1:2)]
```

Comment: I like both solutions but particularly this merge(merge( Nice!